# ¿Cómo obtener ítems de objeto de tipo IEnumerable C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

Tengo un objeto de este tipo:

```
  System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<SalesOrder>
```

Cuando realizo un debug del código dentro de objeto en la propiedad source me dice que existen ítems,  pero no he podido acceder a ellos aunque he probado una variedad de código que he encontrado en la red.
Dice que su enumerator es:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<SalesOrder>.Enumerator
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Modelo SalesOrder:

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mobileDateCreated")]
    public DateTimeOffset MobileDateCreated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customer")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdBy")]
    public TedBy CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public TypeClass Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("exported")]
    public bool Exported { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deleted")]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sellerComment")]
    public string SellerComment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("scheduledDateForDelivery")]
    public DateTimeOffset ScheduledDateForDelivery { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accuracy")]
    public double Accuracy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tookInPlace")]
    public bool TookInPlace { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("priceList")]
    public object PriceList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalSales")]
    public double TotalSales { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("billable")]
    public bool Billable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("billed")]
    public bool Billed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("promoIds")]
    public object PromoIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("promoNames")]
    public object PromoNames { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("networkSignalQuality")]
    public long NetworkSignalQuality { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("creationSource")]
    public string CreationSource { get; set; }
}


public partial class TypeClass
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("enabled")]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public partial class TedBy
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("enabled")]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("isReturn")]
    public bool IsReturn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product")]
    public Product_GET Product { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public double Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("comments")]
    public object Comments { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("originalPrice")]
    public long OriginalPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isReward")]
    public bool IsReward { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("discount")]
    public object Discount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("promoIds")]
    public object PromoIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("promoNames")]
    public object PromoNames { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: el ToList() no te anduvo? tiene ese metodo definido...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537528/how-to-convert-system-linq-enumerable-wherelistiteratorint-to-listint aqui la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

no tengo la clase Ienumerable que tienes como resultado pero a ver si te ayuda esto:

```
List<SalesOrder> so_list = IEnumerable<SalesOrder>.ToList();
```

donde `IEnumerable<SalesOrder>` es la clase que te retorna tu consulta.

Saludos.